# HID Device that would allow to track usage

Tags: usb, usb-device, hid

Would it be possible to implement a HID device that would be capable of tracking computer usage - such as - 
1/ computer being woken up
2/ Keyboard, mouse and/or touchscreen being active

A HID device (USB-device) that would "subscribe" to those events/actions.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

No. USB HID standards do not have these options.

Comment: Depends a bit. If the computer suspends the USB bus when it goes to sleep, that is certainly noticeable.

Comment: @chris if. And if it doesn't have usb wake support. And it won't be able to tell sleep from power on. But that's only a third of the question. And not something supported by usb hid, that's custom coding.

Comment: You seem to forget that any USB HID device is a USB device first.  Plenty of perfectly everyday HID devices do respond to USB suspend.

Comment: @chris you seem to forget op is asking for a usb hid device to log other device activity somehow.

Comment: It's not clear that what the poster wants to know is distinct from what the USB suspend may on some system represent.  Of course others may not activate that at all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so you think USB Suspend reports ***2/ Keyboard, mouse and/or touchscreen being active*** to random usb devices?